# Tax on remittances from UAE to India

Tags: taxes, india, money-transfer, international-transfer, uae

My son is working for a company in the UAE. His salary is paid there in AED and every month he transfers some money to his mother's account in SBI. Does my wife have to pay tax on that?

Answer (score 1):

> My wife has to pay tax on that?

No. This will be treated as gift to your wife.

As a son he can gift unlimited amount to his mother without any tax implication to his mother.

If the amounts are large more than few lacs, best talk to CA and get a gift deed executed. Keep the paper work intact, i.e. details of the transfer, debit to your son's account with corresponding credit to your wife's account.